# Print out everything from table 1 and matching data from table 2

Tags: sql

I am trying to learn sql and I came across a basic question. This problem mainly focuses on the join, which join to use in order to execute the correct data.
What queries I should write to validate and compare between these two tables?
Let's say I have two tables (parent and child):

Parent has two columns
ID(Primary key) |  data1

Child also has two columns
PID(Foreign key) | data2

And I am trying to print out everything from parent and record from child(if matching..)

What query should I write?
I have these lines so far:

```
Select * from parent,
(
Select * child
(
If ( parent.data1 = child.data2)
))

Order by parent.id;
```

Comment: Find an online course on SQL. You join by comparing foreign key to primary key. `SELECT * FROM parent JOIN child ON (parent.ID = child.PID);`

Comment: just `JOIN` will print out everything from both of the tables. So it can't be JOIN/INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to print out everything from parent and record from child(if matching..)

You are describing a left join:

```
select p.*, c.data2
from parent p
left join child c on c.pid = p.id
```